# Load as3 into as2 work only on _root

Tags: actionscript-3, migration, actionscript-2, localconnection

i made a simple test example in as2. This contains two buttons with the following handlers.

_root:

```
on (release)
{
    this.loadMovie("AS3.swf");      
}
```

_root.test.testmc:

```
on (release)
{
    test.testmc.loadMovie("AS3.swf");       
}
```

The AS3.swf is a video player(using youtube as3 api). If i load it into _root it works, but if i want to load it into any other place it doesn't. I searched and found this from adobe:

> "SWF files written in ActionScript 1.0 or 2.0 cannot load SWF files written in ActionScript 3.0. This means that SWF files authored in Flash 8 or Flex Builder 1.5 or earlier versions cannot load ActionScript 3.0 SWF files.
>
> The only exception to this rule is that an ActionScript 2.0 SWF file can replace itself with an ActionScript 3.0 SWF file, as long as the ActionScript 2.0 SWF file hasn't previously loaded anything into any of its levels. An ActionScript 2.0 SWF file can do this through a call to loadMovieNum(), passing a value of 0 to the level parameter."

Is the "_root part" of my code working because of the above "exception rule"? I am new to flash(yeah you could ask why i started with as2, unfortunately not my choice...) and i wonder if my thinking is right. Also if there is any sort of workaround(other than rewrite everything in AS3), let me know(maybe use of localconnection?).

Comment: I believe that you are correct, and that `_root.loadMovie()` is working as an equivalent to `loadMovieNum()`.  I'm afraid that if you do not want to load your player swf into the root then you might have to consider either porting your application to AS3 or rewriting your video player using YouTube's AS2 api: https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference_as2

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately the youtube as2 api will continue to operate until October 14, i guess after that date it wouldn't work. I think i will try to convince the boss to forget AS2 and invest in porting everything to AS3.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

on root of as2:

```
test.testmc.loadMovie("AS3.swf");
```

or in the mc u want the as3 player:

```
this.loadMovie("AS3.swf");
```

Your second code is calling `test.testmc.test.testmc` because it is already placed in the "testmc" so you dont need to reference it with the full path. It's recommended that you use relative paths for things like this.

So, inside the mc `testmc` you just need to do `this.loadmovie` instead of searching for `test.testmc` INSIDE testmc.

Hope that was what you're looking for.

Comment: I am getting the same results(not working). I am pretty sure my code is correct, just probably failed to explain it in the opening post, sorry for that. Anyway, thanks for the try.